# Google Translator popup detect non-english word on the site

Tags: asp.net, google-translate

I have a website that one of it's pages is showing Google translator popup with the message "translate page from German". My site is an English/French website and am not using any German words.

I copied the "view page source" content to the google translate site and notices that the detect language feature is showing "DUTCH-DETECTED", "GREEK-DETECTED" for the hidden value in "__VIEWSTATE".

I made a html page in my local pc and copy the viewstate value to a hidden field to simulate it in my local but it didn't show me the Google translator popup.

Any idea how I can fix this issue in our website? my site is an ASP.Net site.

Thanks,
Maryam